# Are there major drawbacks to use GoLand for Vue/TS?

Tags: webstorm, goland

I use GoLand for Go development and WebStorm for Vue and Typescript. This is basic development where I mostly use the hinting (suggestions) for classes, types, etc.

GoLand supports both Go and Vue/TS. If I only use it (and not separately GoLand and WebStorm), what am I missing from the most important features? (the ones wildly used)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All features from WebStorm you can find in GoLand. You just need to install some plugins that don't come bundled with it (NodeJS, for example) through *Preferences/Settings | Plugins*, as GoLand includes only basic stuff (JavaScript, TypeScript, CSS/HTML editing support, JavaScript debugger, etc.) out of the box.

According to: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/faq-about-goland.html#in-addition-to-go-which-web-technologies-does-goland-support

> In addition to tools for core Go development, GoLand supports JavaScript, TypeScript, Node.js, SQL, Databases, Docker, Kubernetes, Terraform, and other technologies.

Comment: Is the opposite supported, ie can you run go projects easily in Webstorm, or are those plugins not available to that IDE?

Comment: Go plugin is available for IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate only, @Tor.